# Assigning a key-value pair from a dict to a DataDrame is not working in Julia 1.1

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, julia, data-conversion

I'm attempting to construct a `DataFrame` from a `Dict` in Julia 1.1. The keys in the dictionary are the column names and the values are vectors containing, well, the values that the column should have. I though it would be as straightforward as

```
df = DataFrame()
for (key,value) in datadict
  df[key] = value
end
```

but this throws a `ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Array{String,1}, ::String)`. Instead of using tha variable `key` directly, I also tried passing a symbol `:key` as the column name, as in `df[:key] = value`, which removes the error message but only inserts the first key-value-pair into the dataframe as a column, with `key` as the column name:

```
10×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ key        │
│     │ String     │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2019-03-04 │
│ 2   │ 2019-03-05 │
│ 3   │ 2019-03-06 │
│ 4   │ 2019-03-07 │
│ 5   │ 2019-03-08 │
│ 6   │ 2019-03-09 │
│ 7   │ 2019-03-10 │
│ 8   │ 2019-03-11 │
│ 9   │ 2019-03-12 │
│ 10  │ 2019-03-13 │
```

This is obviously not what I want. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work :

```
using DataFrames
datadict = Dict(1 => ["2019-03-04", "2019-03-04"], 2 => ["1996-26-12", "1996-25-12"])
df = DataFrame()
for (key, value) in datadict
       df[Symbol(key)] = value
end
```

You have to create a Symbol of your key with `Symbol(key)`.